# Inno Setup - "An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format" when trying to install NetFx3 feature

Tags: sql-server, windows, batch-file, installation, inno-setup

I'm working on an installation script with Inno Setup and I need to install SQL Server 2008 R2 Express if it's not already installed.

As it requires .NET Framework 3.5 SP1 to be installed, I've downloaded and tried to install the netfx35.exe from my script. But I cannot perform the installation directly, I have to do it through the "Add roles and features wizard". To do it automatically, I use Dism, but I have an error when I try to enable the NetFx3 feature. Here are some information about the actions I've performed:

(The script is developed under Windows 7 Professional SP1 64 bits and it's run under Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard 64 bits on which I am logged in as administrator.)

**Step 1**: Make sure the command line is correct.

On the Windows Server machine, I have run the following command line both in the cmd prompt and in a batch file to make sure the command I'm trying to execute is correct and does the right job.

```
Dism /online /enable-feature /featurename:NetFx3 /NoRestart
```

The result was what I expected, the .Net Framework 3.5 was enabled.

**Step 2**: Try to execute the same command line from an Inno Setup script.

```
Exec('Dism', ' /online /enable-feature /featurename:NetFx3 /NoRestart', '', SW_SHOW, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode);
MsgBox(SysErrorMessage(ResultCode), true, MB_OK);
```

When I compile and execute my script I get an error "An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format". After some research, I've found similar cases due to the architecture (trying to run a 32bit app in a 64bit mode). Thus, I've tried with the following commands:

```
Dism.exe /online /enable-feature /featurename:NetFx3 /NoRestart
C:\Windows\System32\Dism.exe /online /enable-feature /featurename:NetFx3 /NoRestart
C:\Windows\SysWOW64\Dism.exe /online /enable-feature /featurename:NetFx3 /NoRestart
```

Even if I run the batch from Inno Setup, it doesn't work. I suspect it being from admin permissions but in the Inno Setup function *IsAdminLoggedOn* returns True.

Can anybody help me ? I don't know what to do anymore.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: And the console when you were running those command lines were elevated with admin rights ? If not, you may try to run it with `ExecAsOriginalUser`, but that's just a wild guess related to your rights suspicion.

Comment: I've tried with `ExecAsOriginalUser` but same result. The command opens a console window and closes just after the display of the version.

Comment: You can always [`edit the question`](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/21986988/edit) if you need to include more information... From what you've provided so far I can only suggest to run always a 32-bit version of the `Dism` since Inno Setup is a 32-bit app., but I can't say why it fails if you tried even that. Still I'm wondering, why can't you install the framework directly...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the solution.

The problem with DISM was that it's 32-bit version was called by Inno Setup and an error was raised because the OS is on 64-bit.

I just added the following paramater to the Setup group:

```
ArchitecturesInstallIn64BitMode=x64
```

I don't know if it has side effects, but in my case it worked.